# contains() method is not working for Arrays.asList in java

Tags: java, string, list, arraylist, collections

I have a string object that looks like:

```
String color = "black, pink, blue, yellow";
```

Now I want to convert it into an array and find a color. Something like this:

```
boolean check = Arrays.asList(color).contains("pink");
```

Which always gives false.

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: In the array there is no `String` `"pink"`, did you split the content and trim it, or did you expect `Arrays.asList(color)` to magically split the original `String` into a logical array for each colour?

Comment: You need to split the string, `asList` does not do that.

Comment: @Teddu In the above code you no need to convert `color` string to `list`. you can directly use `String` class contains like `color.contains("pink")`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your string variable `color` is not an array, so first of all you need to create array from that string variable with `split(String dilemeter)` method and create `ArrayList` from splitted string, like this:

```
List<String> arrList = Arrays.asList(color.split(", "));
```

After that you can check if `arrList` contains some element:

```
boolean check = arrList.contains("pink");
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this code snippet:

```
boolean check = Arrays.asList("black", "pink", "blue", "yellow").contains("pink");
```

I wouldn't recommend using String to store multiple values.

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is related to the fact that `color` is a `String` not an `array` so `Arrays.asList(color)` will create a `List` which contains only one element that is `"black, pink, blue, yellow"` that is why it returns `false`.

You need first to convert it as an `array` using [`split(String regex)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String-) as next:

```
// Here the separator used is a comma followed by a whitespace character
boolean check = Arrays.asList(color.split(",\\s")).contains("pink")
```

---

If you only want to know if `color` contains "`pink`", you can also consider using [`String#contains(CharSequence s)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#contains-java.lang.CharSequence-)

```
boolean check = color.contains("pink");
```

Answer (score 2):

you need to split() the string

Comment: but not just with a no-args `split()`

Comment: Indeed not, there isn't any no-arg split method on string.  But the javadoc on the other split methods will tell the op the rest.

Answer (score 1):

Your color variable is a string. When you convert to a list it will be inserted as a single string. you can check the output of the following

> Arrays.asList(color).size()

The above will always return 1, stating that your understanding that a string with comma's won't be automagically split and converted into a list.

you can split at every **'** followed by a space as shown below to get your expected output.

> System.out.println(Arrays.asList(color.split(", ")).contains("pink"));

**The space is important in the split because your string contains spaces.**

Answer (score 1):

split colors to "," , turn that into an arraylist and check if a string is present:

```
    String color = "black, pink, blue, yellow";
    boolean isThere = Arrays.asList(color.split(",")).contains("black");

    System.out.println("is black present: " + isThere);
```